# How can I repair the metal cover on my exterior door trim?

Tags: repair

How do I fix it?!  Its a thin metal material that's nailed onto a wood frame. I live on a rental property and am hoping to be able to get my deposit back with this repair.  The guy at home depot said I need a contractor but it can't be that complicated.

[image]

Comment: Have you contacted a company that supplies aluminum siding? You are looking for a specialized trim piece.

Answer (score 1):

A siding contractor could easily make a new piece of bent metal trim for you. But the cost would probably be 150-200 dollars.

Or you can order a custom bent piece in the same style and color from [trimbender](https://www.trimbender.com/window-trim) online. Take careful measurements and enter them under the matching profile. Select the texture and color and your done. They will make the piece and ship it to you. Or you could replace the door trim boards wit a [pvc trim board](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Veranda-3-4-in-x-3-1-2-in-x-8-ft-White-PVC-Trim-6-Pack-827000002/203640250) of same size from big box stores.

Answer (score 1):

The exterior of your door frame is called *flashing* and it serves to protect the actual (most likely wood, if you are in the U.S.) frame the door is installed in. It is typically thin sheet metal.

Find a sheetmetal place in your area and they will have a sheetmetal brake, the tool you will need to bend your custom sized piece out of stock coil. Usually, as is the case at the one where I go to in my area, if you buy stock coil from them, they will let you use the brake for free. Good luck.

[image]